# piecewise scale in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite, vega

here's ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qwjnrxy/1/) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/eflister/f34b85ac7b95a039283c060f0b450123) you can paste into [vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/custom/vega-lite)) a vega-lite project i'm working on.  it's an interactive map of zip codes that lets you view a timeline of covid infections.

the color and y-scale are `symlog`, but that overemphasizes some rare negative values in the dataset (i guess when the health department reverses previously declared positive cases).

[image]

i'd like to use a [piecewise](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#piecewise) scale to give less magnification to negative values.  but when i add the following to my `y-encoding` `scale`, it seems to collapse the data to a single y value.

```json
{ "domain": [-0.2 , 0, 1.4]
, "range" : [-0.05, 0, 1.4]
}
```

[image]

so what's the right way to specify a piecewise scale?

a few other questions i have:

- the selection colors for each zip are currently chosen as `nominal` `sinebow` entries by zip, but since zip codes are spatially correlated, selecting nearby zip codes yields unhelpfully similarly colored lines (green in the example above). i think it would be better to use n equally spaced `sinebow` entries for n selections, but how can these be computed at selection time?
- is there any way to include the `Line`'s `point` just when it is selected (not just using selection-dependent `opacity` or `size`), rather than including a separate `Circle` `Mark` `layer` `filter`ed to the selection, as i have done?  like setting the `shape` `encoding` to `null` or something?
- is there any way to get a `tooltip` along the `Line`s, not just at datapoints?  i see it would be ambiguous which point's data to inspect, but i would think `Line`s should address this.
- looks like choropleth zoom+pan has been [deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471426/how-can-i-zoom-into-a-map-using-vega-lite) [for](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3306) a [couple](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1324) [years](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3673), even though `vega` [can do it](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/zoomable-world-map/).  what makes this so hard for `vega-lite` to pick up?  are there any workarounds?  i would consider switching to `vega` (also for new labeling support that's not yet in `vega-lite`), but what is the best way to do this?  i happen to use [`hvega`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hvega) in `haskell` to generate my `vega-lite` and would rather continue to maintain as much as possible from there, is it possible to avoid switching to doing everything in `vega`, only using it when `vega-lite` is insufficient?  i'm picturing something like a `vega` instruction to `import from vega-lite`...

Answer (score 0):

> specify a piecewise scale?

currently `range` is not abstract, it is in concrete presentation units.  in this case, 0 is at the top and goes positive downwards in pixels.  i filed a proposal to change this here: https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/2954

> n equally spaced sinebow entries for n selections, but how can these be computed at selection time?

filed feature request here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7014.  i don't think order/number selected is available, but many parameters can take expressions as values that could in principle be evaluated after each selection.
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/mark.html#color
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/types.html#exprref
perhaps a selection predicate could be used to count the number currently selected?
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/predicate.html#selection-predicate

> include the Line's point just when it is selected

on selection condition change it from `False`? https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/line.html#properties  or on selection draw a whole new line with different `point`, only way to have it draw on top of the unselected.

> tooltip along the Lines, not just at datapoints?

https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/6851#issuecomment-718103153

> choropleth zoom+pan

waiting...